Buckling length of column
I was given this question to find the buckling length of the non-sway frame of column AB.
The general equation is v" + (ω^2) v = MB/EI + Vx/EI,
Taking B as origin, the boundary condition provided was v(x=0)= 0, v(x=L)=0, v'(x=0)= θB, v'(x=L)= 0,
However, I still cant reach the final equation of in terms ωL, Can anyone help ? enter image description here



